# How to filter the filtered option tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt

I had finished filtering Series dropdown with the application dropdown. What I want now is to filter the results of the first filtering using the case size dropdown.

Here is the code of the dropdown:

```html
<select name="series" onchange="changeCalc()" id="idCalcSelect" class="CalcSelect">
  <option selected="1" style="display:none;">Series</option>
  <xsl:for-each select="//calc">
    <xsl:sort select="@series" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>
    <option>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@series[contains(substring(.,13,2),'A')]">
          <xsl:attribute name="app">Automotive</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:attribute name="app">Commercial</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:attribute name="style">display: normal;</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="@calc-id"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="caseSize"><xsl:value-of select="substring(@series,1,9)"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:variable name="series" select="@series"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($series,10,5)"/>
    </option>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <option id="noSeries" style="display: none;">NO SERIES AVAILABLE</option>
</select>
```

What should I add with my script, see my code below:

```js
var selectedApp = "Automotive";
jq("#selectApp").on("change", function() {
  selectedApp = jq(this).find('option:selected').text();
  jq("select[name='series'] > option").each(function() {
    var attrApp = jq(this).attr("app");
    if (selectedApp == attrApp) {
      this.show();
    } else {
      this.hide();
    }
  });
});

var selectedCS;
jq("#selectCaseSize").on("change", function() {
  selectedCS = jq(this).find('option:selected').text();
  jq("select[name='series'] > option").each(function() {
    var attrCS = jq(this).attr("caseSize");
    if (selectedCS == attrCS) {
      this.show();
    } else {
      this.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

So what I want here is to filter the results of the first filtering. Whether if you use the case size dropdown first or the application dropdown first.

EDIT: I need to filter them using the attributes.

Comment: Thank you for editing @ObsidianAge